# using internal css in php

Tags: php, css

I want to run the following code

```
echo "<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

p {color: white; }
body {background-color: black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>White text on a black background!</p>
</body>
</html>";
}
```

but this code don't run.However,when i run

```
echo "<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>White text on a black background!</p>
</body>
</html>";
}
```

the code runs well and

> White text on a black background!

gets displayed.Am i including the internal css the right way?.

Thanks.

Comment: "this code don't run" is not an error message - make sure you've got error reporting configured in such a way that you can find error messagse and please include them in your posts.

Comment: Double quotes for style type have not been escaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a slash before your double quotes

```
echo "<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
p {color: white; }
body {background-color: black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>White text on a black background!</p>
</body>
</html>";
```

Or use single quotes so they don't interfear with your HTML quotes;

```
echo '<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p {color: white; }
body {background-color: black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>White text on a black background!</p>
</body>
</html>';
```

Or just dont use PHP?

```
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p {color: white; }
body {background-color: black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>White text on a black background!</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
```

Answer (score 2):

Better way (index.php) :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

p {color: white; }
body {background-color: black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//PHP Statements
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting using double-quotes, so the script dies when it hits the "text/css" as it assumes that you are finishing your double quote block.

Either put an escaping slash before your double quotes i.e. \"text/css\" or use single quotes i.e. 'text/css'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the quotes in the `style type="text/css"`. Because the string to echo is delimited by quotes, these quotes mess things up.

Either use single quotes (`'`), or escape the double quotes with backslashes (`\"`).

Answer (score 0):

You have double-quotes in the string you want to echo. So, you need to escape them if you have double-quotes delimited string, i.e. you must replace all occurrences of `"` with `\"`. You can avoid this escaping if you choose to delimit your string using single-quote rather than double-quote. Yes, you can have single-quoted strings in PHP. The only difference is that in single-quoted strings, variables are not expanded to its values and escape sequences lose their special meaning.

However, a neater way would be to use `heredoc` syntax as shown below.

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p {color: white; }
body {background-color: black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>White text on a black background!</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
?>
```

An even better way to be just get out of PHP mode. e.g.

```
<?php
    // PHP code here.
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p {color: white; }
body {background-color: black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>White text on a black background!</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    // PHP code here.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly escape your strings, PHP now reads it as:

```
<?php
echo "<html><head><style type=";
text/css
"> p {color: white; } body {background-color: black; } </style>";
?>
```

Which obviously isn't correct PHP

You need to escape double quotes in your double quoted string, single quotes in your single quoted string or use [NOWDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)/[HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Valid examples:

```
<?php
echo "<style type=\"text/css\">";
echo "<style type='text/css'>";
echo '<style type="text/css">';   // This one minimizes escapes but still uses the standard double-quotes in HTML, I'd advise it
echo '<style type=\'text/css\'>';
echo <<<HTML
    <style type="text/css">
HTML;
?>
```